# Deep belief network with scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I know that `scikit-learn` has an implementation for Restricted Boltzmann Machines, but does it have an implementation for Deep Belief Networks?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be in the documentation

Comment: For deep belief network in python, Theano seems to be the way to go. The dev are machine learning people and their tutorial covers deep belief network: http://www.deeplearning.net/tutorial/DBN.html?highlight=belief

Comment: These links may be helpful https://github.com/albertbup/deep-belief-network, https://github.com/lmjohns3/theanets

Answer (score 6):

It does not, but it appears that the `nolearn` module does.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nolearn